# filter from an object and more object that related in django?

Tags: django

This Is my models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Customer_Type)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Sale(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Sale %s (%i)" % (self.type, self.id)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=3)

class Unitary_Sale(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=3)
    sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale)
```

Views.py

```
def get_filter_result(self, customer_type='' volume_sale=''):
        qdict = {}
        if customer_type != '':
            qdict['type__name'] = customer_type
            qdict['active']=True
        #WHAT I AM GOING TO DO NEXT
   ***  if volume_sale != '':
            pass # This point I am asking :)
        #IT RETURN CUSTOMERS BASE ON PARAMS.
        queryset = Customer.objects.filter(**qdict)
```

***The volume_sale is:

```
units=Unitary_Sale.objects.all()
>>> units=Unitary_Sale.objects.all()
>>> for unit in units:
...    print unit.sale.customer
...    print unit.book,unit.sale.total
...
Sok nara
Khmer Empire (H001) 38.4
Sok nara
killing field (H001) 16

San ta
khmer krom (H001) 20
San ta
Khmer Empire (H001) 20
>>>
{<Customer: Sok nara>: Decimal("56.4"), <Customer: san ta>: Decimal("40")}

Decimal("56.4") , Decimal("40") this is the volume_sale
```

I could not find the ways to make the filter from difference object as in my case.
It will be great if everyone here help in this stuck? Thanks.

Comment: This is very long; my eyes glazed over in the first code sample. Could you ask the question more succintly - perhaps by trimming the code sample down to just the neccessary parts?

Comment: yes of cause.Now I am trimmed down.thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand what you're trying to do. What are you trying to with volume_sale? What criteria are you wanting to use to filter? Where are you trying to pull data from?

Comment: With volume_sale I am try to get the results of customers.
the volume_sale($) is the input field from user.and pass to url
?customer_type=TDO&sale_volume=12.so will get customers list that has volume_sale<=12. thanks for you keep track.

Comment: just to see if I understand ... You're trying to find a query that will determine the TOTAL amount of money (volume_sale) that each customer has spent and then filter that list to find all of the customers that have less then 12 (or some such number)

Comment: @JudoWill You super right !sorry for my English that everyone Can not understand.

Comment: @python As long as you speak code everyone will understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool, this actually pretty easy to implement.  I used the django annotation feature documented [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate-args-kwargs) and [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Sum
query = Customer.objects.all().annotate(volume_sale = Sum('Sale__total'))
query.filter(volume_sale < 12.0) #return all customers that have purchased less than 12.0
query[0].volume_sale #you can even get it on the Customer objects given back
```

Django will take care of the database joins for you.  It will put this extra field into each instance of the model that you can filter, order_by and access in templates or views.

Comment: I used Django version 1.0.2 final, 
ImportError: cannot import name sum

Comment: @python ... did you capitalize the 'S' in Sum ? ... your copy-paste has a lower-case 's'

Comment: In fact I tried both.from django.db.models import Sum
and from django.db.models import sum

Comment: from django.db.models import Avg, Max, Min, Count
all of this I can not import

Comment: hmmm ... that I have no idea about ... maybe something weird in your path ... but then you'd have problems running the ORM completely ... might be another good stackoverflow question ;)

Comment: The aggregation features including Sum were only added in Django 1.1.

Comment: okay,you are right @Daniel .after I changed to 1.1 it works. !

Comment: wow ... I don't know why I thought it was added in 1.0 ... great catch @Daniel

Comment: @JuboWill  It works when I changed to django1.1 .Are there other ways for my version 1.0.2 final.? I dont wish to change django version.THX

Comment: @python Somone smarter than me could figure out how to use the `queryset.select()` and put the raw SQL in there ... but I use the ORM because my SQL-fu is pretty crummy.  You could probably post another SO-question, link to this one and specifically mention that you're using django 1.0 and need an answer without using aggregation.